# Override implicitly inherited service in Icinga

Tags: icinga

I have a hostgroup A for which several services are defined using the `hostgroup_name` directive in their service template. Among several other hostgroups which hosts are also members of hostgroup A there is one hostgroup for which I want to override one of the services that it implicitly inherits from hostgroup A. Is this possible?

I tried defining a service for this particular hostgroup with the same service description but that had no effect.

I also tried to exclude the hostgroup from the service template I mentioned with no success. The hostgroup where I want to override a service is defined after the service template and thus `!hostgroup-b` cannot be expanded.

Is there a simple solution to this or should I reorganize my configs?

---

Example:

```
# hostgroup-a.cfg

# hostgroup A
define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name hostgroup-a
}

define host {
        name host-a
        register 0
        use linux-server
        hostgroups hostgroup-a
}

# service template for services for hostgroup A
define service {
        name hostgroup-a-service
        register 0
        use generic-service
        hostgroup_name hostgroup-a
}

# PING example service
define service {
        use hostgroup-a-service
        service_description PING
        check_command check-host-alive
}
```

For the following hostgroup I want to remove or override the `PING` service implicitly inherited from `hostgroup-a`.

```
# hostgroup-b.cfg

# hostgroup b
define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name hostgroup-b
}

define host {
        name host-b
        use host-a
        register 0
        hostgroups +hostgroup-b
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my configuration was too complex so I just removed the implicitly inherited services which I wanted to override and defined them separately for each hostgroup to reduce complexity. This way it's easier to maintain.

Comment: Dammit, no :) I have the same problem. So does this [guy](http://serverfault.com/questions/612930/overriding-nagios-hostgroup-service-with-host-service).